# AWS IAM user not able to see Billing and Cost Management Dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-billing

I need to access Billing and Cost Management Dashboard through IAM user. Currently It is being accessed through root user.

According to [AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_billing.html) I have created an IAM user and granted full access of Billing Policy, but it doesn't work.

Here are the screen shots.

**IAM User getting error**

[image: IAM User getting error]

**Billing Policy assigned to IAM user**
[image]

Comment: Have you allowed IAM access to billing (in account settings/preferences when logged as root)? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_billing.html

Comment: Thank you, I'll do that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow IAM users to access the billing information, you need the IAM policy and to allow IAM access to billing.

This is done as the root account in the settings of the account.

more information here: [docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_billing.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_billing.html)